# C# .NET 7 - How to connect to WCF service using HTTPS and cookie authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, cookies, soap, .net-7.0

I am struggling with this for weeks now, tried everything I could find on internet, but nothing works.
Biggest problems is - it works seamlessly in .NET 4.8 with default WCF scaffold, however .NET Core has WCF reworked and this one I can not figure out.

So, the authentication process has three parts.

1. Get XSFR token from web page, this is simple HttpClient.GetAsync towards web page which returns XSFR cookie in response.
2. Get SessionID by calling REST auth method, also simple and works with HttpClient.PostAsync.
3. Call HTTPS WCF service by sending XSFR token and SessionID as cookies. No go.

I used Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.3) to scaffold wsdl file.

I tried different bindings and I learned that `Security.Mode` has to be `System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.Transport` otherwise I get error that "http" is expected but "https" found in URL and does not work.

However, when I do set security mode to Transport, I get error:
`'The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.'`

`Anonymous` changes depending on `Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType`.

As for sending cookies, I tried two different methods:

1. `OperationContextScope`:

```cs
        using (new OperationContextScope(port.InnerChannel)) {
            var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(Config.URL_APP_ORIGIN);
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequest.Headers.Add(HEADER_X_XSRF_TOKEN, xsrfToken?.Value);
            httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, sessionId?.ToString());
            httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, xsrfToken?.ToString());
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequest);

            await IspisVerzije(port);
            // await IspisAllowedValues(port);
            port.Close();
        }
```

2. `HttpHeaderMessageInspector`

```cs
// Implementation of partial method in scaffolded web service reference
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials) {
        var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            ["HEADER_X_XSRF_TOKEN"] = Program.xsrfToken?.ToString(),
            ["Cookie"] = "Basic " + Program.sessionId?.ToString(),
            ["Cookie"] = "Basic " + Program.xsrfToken?.ToString()
        };

        var behaviour = new AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior(headers);
        serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behaviour);
    }
}

public class HttpHeaderMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector {
    private Dictionary<string, string> Headers;

    public HttpHeaderMessageInspector(Dictionary<string, string> headers) {
        Headers = headers;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) { }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel) {
        // ensure the request header collection exists
        if (request.Properties.Count == 0 || !request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name)) {
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, new HttpRequestMessageProperty());
        }

        // get the request header collection from the request
        var HeadersCollection = ((HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name]).Headers;

        // add our headers
        foreach (var header in Headers) HeadersCollection[header.Key] = header.Value;

        return null;
    }
}

public class AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior {
    private IClientMessageInspector HttpHeaderMessageInspector;

    public AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior(Dictionary<string, string> headers) {
        HttpHeaderMessageInspector = new HttpHeaderMessageInspector(headers);
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(HttpHeaderMessageInspector);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
}
```

I used Fiddler to inspect outgoing requests and cookies are present in request.

This is raw request sent by working .NET Framework 4.8 version:

```
POST https://zupit-test.gov.hr/services/integration/v2 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)
X-XSRF-TOKEN: 7280e4c2-6dd1-4ed4-9a35-91c22c172dfd
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo0dR90lQHnFDopiVLjbd/0IAAAAAxYMKfS4zuEWC0d5bf6byLKVx4ImkhWZLr+qCOPCMN3gACQAA
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""
Host: zupit-test.gov.hr
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=7280e4c2-6dd1-4ed4-9a35-91c22c172dfd; JSESSIONID=B232706D460BE6C5FC5981826B36E9EB; TS01a2529c=01402d66b9a555cd86492a154020763ed07f0c7bbe2dbd6487ca2abfa0cfa1b3c533cde8a1335c973f7c6d5c24cdee6f743a38b5b5c0b26948152fee150d6abba41ea0e8cd
Content-Length: 301
Expect: 100-continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><getVersion xmlns="http://zupit.gov.hr/integration/v2" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

And this is raw request sent by .NET 7 version:

```
POST https://zupit-test.gov.hr/services/integration/v2 HTTP/1.1
Host: zupit-test.gov.hr
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
X-XSRF-TOKEN: e62fe08b-e7ea-4fd7-88d7-28f58aa45018
Cookie: JSESSIONID=77C6A62B4A0B62DDDFAD8C534EA9D2A9,XSRF-TOKEN=e62fe08b-e7ea-4fd7-88d7-28f58aa45018
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 573

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://zupit.gov.hr/integration/v2/IntegrationWSv2/getVersionRequest</a:Action><a:MessageID>urn:uuid:3aef24b7-6c08-4a85-bff4-fd0dbcf7ce1d</a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://zupit-test.gov.hr/services/integration/v2</a:To></s:Header><s:Body><getVersion xmlns="http://zupit.gov.hr/integration/v2"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

And this is server response for .NET 7 request:

```
HTTP/1.1 403
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=915dea61-d5a4-4c63-ad85-51f92df31f67; Path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2022 07:42:34 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains
Set-Cookie: TS01a2529c=01402d66b972abf2e18b994c3e4a4342cb1a60809c602d5bd0ebfb7953d22b3d635225a9b013d6108d2efd22d658d57c1de898f2709b920c1a01fefeda45b6c6746a57884d; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

8e
{"timestamp":"2022-12-22T07:42:35.272Z","error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/services/integration/v2","showServerMessage":false}
0
```

Is this HTTPS issue or difference of generated SOAP XML in .NET 7?
Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: Hello, have you tried to modify firewall settings or turn off firewall operation? Secondly, I think these documents are helpful to you.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

Comment: Hi, it is not a firewall issue, .NET 4.8 example works properly from the same machine  which is why mention article does not help, it is ASP.NET 4 document addressing cross-site anti-forgery and this seems to be either .NET Core binding issue or .NET Core scaffolding issue (generating SOAP XML not compatible with server)